# Loking for custom split normals tool

Tags: normals

community!
I have a mesh of character GG Xrd game and found that they used analogue custom split normals data. 
I know, they used Autodesk Softimage soft for editing custom normals. 
I know some analogue of this for Blender, like Blend4web and some scripts, but  i can`t see a way to use it for edititng many split faces at once. 
I see on this video  [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/iH3p8N7qbv8) Softimage has addons for editing normals trough vertex painting. Is there any solution for blenders?
On screenshot  - imported models from .dae  file with split edges . Btw blender cant mark  sharp edges on importing meshes or mark just invisible? 
Thanks!

[image: custom normals sample]

Comment: Look at this GSoC project: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?427746-GSoC-2017-Normal-Editing-Tools (builds available there) and Y.A.V.N.E add-on.

Comment: there is a good tutorial on using the B4W normal editor https://www.blend4web.com/en/community/article/131/ (https://www.blend4web.com/ru/community/article/130/ Russian)